# How to print nested data structure in a presentable way

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have below sample data & structure and trying to play around to better understand SparkSQL,Pyspark commands.

```
schemaTest="`id` BIGINT NOT NULL,`name` STRING,`address` STRUCT<`number`: INT, `road`: STRING, 
`city`: STRUCT<`name`: STRING, `postcode`: BIGINT>>,`numbers` ARRAY<INT>"

data = [(1,"Smith",(1200,"North Custer RD",("Sugar Land TX",75034)),[2815,2133])]
```

this is what I get from printSchema:

```
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = false)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- address: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- number: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- road: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- city: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- postcode: long (nullable = true)
 |-- numbers: array (nullable = true)
  |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = true)
```

when I query the df , this is how it's represented and I am trying to re-format the "address" column for a better representation:

```
+---+-----+-----------------------------------------------+------------+
|id |name |address                                        |numbers     |
+---+-----+-----------------------------------------------+------------+
|1  |Smith|{1200, North Custer RD, {Sugar Land TX, 75034}}|[2815, 2133]|
+---+-----+-----------------------------------------------+------------+
```

I want it to be more like this:

```
+---+-----+------------------------------------------+------------+
|id |name |address                                   |numbers     |
+---+-----+------------------------------------------+------------+
|1  |Smith|1200 North Custer RD, Sugar Land TX, 75034|[2815, 2133]|
+---+-----+------------------------------------------+------------+
```

I tried explode to see if I can extract but it says mismatch (I am assuming cannot perform explode on structType).

can someone give me an example using withColumn how to reformat the "Address" column?. or if you have any other approach?

Comment: Did @VincentDoba's answer work for you?

Comment: yes it did work.

Comment: Oh, it'd be cool to accept the solution :)

Comment: i thought I did before..:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `concat` built-in function to create a string from several columns, as follows:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

result = input_df.withColumn(
  'address', 
  F.concat(
    F.col('address.number'), 
    F.lit(' '), 
    F.col('address.road'), 
    F.lit(', '), 
    F.col('address.city.name'), 
    F.lit(', '), 
    F.col('address.city.postcode')
  )
)
```